# Use awk to get min-max column values

Tags: awk

Given a file with data such as

```
2015-12-24 22:02 12   9.87 feet  High Tide
2015-12-25 03:33 12  -0.38 feet  Low Tide
2015-12-25 06:11 12   Full Moon
2015-12-25 10:16 12  11.01 feet  High Tide
2015-12-25 16:09 12  -1.29 feet  Low Tide
```

This `awk` command will return a min value in col 4:

```
awk 'min=="" || $4 < min {min=$4} END{ print min}' FS="  " 12--December.txt
```

How do I get it to exclude any line where $4 contains text? I imagine this needs regex but poring over the regex manuals I am lost as to how to do it.

Comment: `poring over regex manuals` and you couldn't find how to only match numbers ? I searched `awk regex` in google and the first result clearly explains how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression comparison on the fourth field as

`$4~/[0-9]+/`

**Test**

```
$ awk '$4~/[0-9]+/ && $4 < min {min=$4} END{print min}' input
-1.29
```

***Note*** *This is a minimised version of the code. You can safely skip some of the statements in the example code as in the test code*

Comment: To exclude if there was an text it may be better to use `$4~/^[^[:alpha:]]+$/ `